# How to allow only one instance of an Activity, without messing up the back stack navigation?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, launchmode

Suppose I have the following Activities:

- A;
- B;
- C, and;
- D;

And I want the Activity C to have only one instance of it.

If the user does the following navigation:

> A → C → B → D → C → B → C

What should I do in my project to, when the user starts going back through its navigation, the result be as following:

> A ← B ← D ← B ← C

---

*I tried using all of the available flag values of `launchMode` in the C's Activity on `AndroidManifest` of the app, but none of them gave the desired result.*

---

My sample `AndroidManifest` activities entries would be as simple as that:

```
<activity
    android:name="A" />

<activity
    android:name="B" />

<activity
    android:name="C"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" />

<activity
    android:name="D" />
```

Comment: Could you Please add the menifest code here?

Comment: @Sunny, I have just edited the question :)

Comment: Whenever you launch any activity from C than finish C as well.

Comment: @ShivamYadav, if I do that, after doing the following navigation A → C → B and start going back, I will not be able to go back to C from B =/

Comment: @AugustoCarmo , one more solution is to use startActivityForResult and finish your acttvity in OnResult of Activity C.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

According to the docs:

> If set in an Intent passed to Context#startActivity, this flag will
>   cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's
>   history stack if it is already running.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of four activities: A, B, C,
>   D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the
>   history stack, with this resulting order: A, C, D, B. This flag will
>   be ignored if FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is also specified.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @SaurabhThorat :). Would that be all? :o. I will try it out.

Comment: Yes. That's all.

Comment: It would probably be useful to explain what this code does.